# How can I determine the performance (rows/second) for a certain query on one of my tables?

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb, mysql-5.5

I want to find the performance (rows/second) for an UPDATE query on one of my tables so I can adjust my WHERE clause to select an appropriate number of records.

The table has around 10 million rows. The WHERE clause uses an index to select rows, and the updates will not change the index. I'm using MySQL 5.5, InnoDB engine.

Bonus question: How can I perform this test in a read replica version of the table? If possible.

Comment: Why do you want to "adjust your where clause"? Surely the where clause is purely functional and you need to update all the rows that need to be updated? Better to do it in one go than in several.

Comment: I will be updating millions of rows. I can't have the table lock up for either reads or writes for a long time. So I can't do a 5 million row update in one go. I want to do it in batches inside a while loop so that MySQL will schedule other queries between loops (hopefully MySQL does this...).

The adjustment is to ensure that each UPDATE statement in my loop runs at sub second speeds (or as fast as I can reasonably get). I have no problem with letting the loop run for several hours if it means it won't lock the table. 

Does that answer your question? @Colin'tHart

Comment: Does MySQL have this problem? The DBMSes that I'm familiar with (Oracle, PostgreSQL) don't have this problem. Regardless, if you need or want to proceed with this approach, I wouldn't bother with trying to determine the performance but rather try to update as many rows per update. One method would be to double the number of rows each update and either stop doubling or backing off a bit when the updates start taking too long.